# Worksheet_SheetChange to wait five minutes after a change

Tags: vba, excel, events

I want to wait five minutes after a change has been made to a sheet, and then re-sort everything.

The code works (aside from repositioning the screen after it runs) but only when I run it with F5, instead of running whenever a change is made.

In the sheet:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call TimeStop
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Open(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Call TimeSetting
End Sub
 
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call TimeStop
    Call TimeSetting
End Sub
```

In the module:

```vb
Dim CurrentTime As Date
Dim SelectWorksheet As Range

Sub TimeSetting()
CurrentTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CurrentTime, _
  Procedure:="SortFile", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub TimeStop()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CurrentTime, _
  Procedure:="SortFile", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub SortFile()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D:D") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily").Sort
    .SetRange Range("Daily")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

I modified code from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3921-excel-save-and-close-workbook-after-inactivity.html.

Comment: There is (to my knowledge) no `Worksheet_SheetChange` event - it's a `Workbook_SheetChange` event, and that fires after the active sheet changes, not when a change occurs on the sheet.  You are **probably** after the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Now, is there any way to keep it from changing where the original screen position on the sheet was after performing this sorting task?

Comment: What do you mean the original screen position?

Comment: If I am focused on line A534 for example, after the sort macro performs, it will put me viewing A1 causing me to scroll down again. Not a big deal but would be nice if it didn't change where I was looking at on the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the name of the sub has to be

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

instead of

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

Secondly. You need to ensure that your excel is macro enabled. (.xlsm)

You may need to include proper range as well in your code, something like:

```
.SetRange Range("Daily!A1:E10")
```

If these are fixed, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code and try again:

```
Sub enableEvents()
Application.enableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If that works, you may want to consider adding this line of code to the beginning of your procedure.